# Create a dynamic search timeline twitter widget

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

I want to do something like this:

https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-timelines/search

The code looks like this:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline"  href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/griechenland" data-widget-id="618063791092297729">#griechenland Tweets</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

But by using this tool I can only crate static timelines for one keyword but I want to do it dynamically. So is there any way to give the keyword as a search parameter to twitter?

I also tried an iFrame but Twitter also blocks that.

Comment: Dynamically what you wanna do? The feed is dynamic, isn't it?

Comment: The feed itself is dynamic but not the search parameter.

Comment: Oh! You want to make a search, that's dynamic on the feed, is it? Man, that's bad! That actually violates the use!

Comment: Thats right. Why does it violate the use?

Comment: The *use* is to show the feeds for a particular search. Right? If you allow to modify that itself, then what's the point?

Comment: The point is that I am working on a software a dashboard with panels e.g. google where only one search is needed and all panels are updated. And twitter is planned too.